# How to use a library such as Sortablejs in an Angular 2.0 app?

Tags: angular, sortablejs

I am starting a new, simple Angular 2.0 app and would like to have lists with items that can be dragged around.

[Sortablejs](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) seems like a fine tool for doing that, but there appear to be several hurdles. As far as I can tell I must:

1) Use [ng-sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/ng-sortable.js) to wrap Sortable.js in an Angular 1 attribute directive.

2) Use the [UpgradeAdapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#using-angular-1-component-directives-from-angular-2-code) to use Angular 1 element directives as Angular 2 components.

3) Use the [ngadapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngadapter) wrapper around the upgrade tool to enable attribute directives in addition to component ones.

Then I need to include all the files and mash together all the instructions.

Starting with an app generated by [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/), I have generated a route, and have npm installed ngadapter, angular, the UpgradeAdapter, and sortablejs. I added this to my index.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/sortablejs/ng-sortable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/angular/angular-min.js"></script>
```

I created an upgrade_adapter.ts file like so

```
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';
export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
```

I edited my main.ts file to look like this:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { MySimpleAppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { upgradeAdapter } from './app/upgrade_adapter';
import { angular } from '../node_modules/angular'; // here's the problem. I don't know how to get angular
import { ngAdapter } from 'ngAdapter/build/ngAdapter';

//create your AngularJS module 
let module = angular.module('MyApp', []);

//create adapter 
let adapter = new ngAdapter(module);

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// bootstrap(MySimpleAppComponent);          // what it was originally
adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['MyApp']); // from ngadapter instructions
```

I'm sure there is a heap of things wrong here but the first error message is

- Cannot find name 'angular'

I'm pretty sure the answer lies within [pages of the system.js documentation](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#amd) but I'm not getting it.Do you know how to set the angular object? Am I going down the right track here? I'm not married to Sortable but I expect that I'll run into the same problems trying to use other libraries with Angular 2 and would like to figure out how to do it.

Is there a better or standard way to use a good javascript library that wasn't made for Angular 2?

Comment: If this is still actual and this is a question about Sortablejs (not a common problem question) you might want to use [an angular wrapper for Sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs).

Comment: I'm asking generally about how to use a library with Angular 2. If you're a beginner, the general answer seems to be - wait for an expert to make something like that that makes it work. I'm glad someone did! It doesn't seem to be a trivial matter.

Comment: First of all this someone is me. But still I don't get your point. You want to use angular 1 library in Angular 2? Or you want to use just a library in Angular 2? Because the Sortablejs library is just a library first of all and only then it has binding to Angular 1. For me your approach here looks like you try to send a package to your neighbour passing the Moon instead of just bringing it next door. Why not just using original sortablejs without any calls to sortablejs angular1 binding? The nice thing of angular2 is that it is perfectly connectable to any library even without bindings.

Comment: That's right. I don't really care how it happens but only that it does. I am asking whether there is a standard procedure for using any javascript library in Angular 2. An adapter, "angular-sortablejs" has been written to accomplish this for "Sortablejs". I assume this was done because it was necessary to do it. I am a beginner and could not have created that adapter nor could I figure out on my own how to use Sortablejs in Angular 2 without such an adapter. If you're good at this, perhaps you'd consider publishing a blog post on doing it or an answer to this question. :)

Comment: well, I'm probably not the best guy to do it... the topic is so huge. Maybe I'll try something when I have time